# I can’t find mobile Hotspot adapter on my widows 10 Home

Tags: windows

Hi I’ve recently installed windows 10home on my pc but mobile Hotspot adapter won’t show wha should I do? Thanks.

Comment: What is your "mobile hotspot adapter"? Are you tethering to a phone? Is it a usb dongle with a sim in? Is it a Wifi personal hotspot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile Hotspot capability is found in Start, Settings, Network and Internet.

It should not matter if your hotspot is active. The screen shot below was taken when my iPhone is not active, but Windows 10 still shows it.

[image: Mobile Hotspot Windows 10]

Then, if your mobile hotspot is active, Windows 10 can see it in the Network icon in the System Tray.

.

[image: Mobile Hotspot in System Tray]